# Why won't messages from friends delete from my homepage?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm adding to add a functionality to my application where a user can delete messages received from friends one by one. I've added a deleteMessage function to my messages model. I then call this within a delete function in my home controller. On my home view I'm then supposed to be able to delete the message by pressing 'delete'. At the moment nothing happens. This will then delete this specific left for them in the messages database too. The db table holds the fields from, to and message. Thanks one again for your help

My home controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
function Home()
{   
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('messages');
     $this->load->model('friends');
     $this->load->model("profiles");
}


  function delete($message)
 {
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
$this->messages->deleteMessage($from, $to, $message);
redirect('home');
 }


function index()
{

 $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
 $membername = $this->session->userdata('membername');
 $viewData['membername'] = $membername;
 $viewData['username'] = $username;
 $viewData['following'] = $this->friends->getFollowing($username);
 $viewData['followers'] = $this->friends->getFollowers($username);
 $viewData['messages'] = $this->messages->getMessages($membername);
 $viewData['friends'] = $this->friends->getFriends($username);


 $this->load->view('shared/header');
 $this->load->view('home/hometitle', $viewData);
 $this->load->view('shared/nav');
 $this->load->view('home/homeview', $viewData);
 $this->load->view('shared/footer');
}
 }
```

Messages model:

```
class Messages extends CI_Model
{



function Messages()
{
parent::__construct();
}



function deleteMessage($from, $to, $message)
{
   $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where('from', $from)->where('to', $to)->where('message', $message);
   $this->db->delete();
  }

}
```

Home view:

```
    <h2> Messages</h2> 
    <ul> 
      <?php foreach($messages as $message):?>
          <li><?=$message['from']?> says...: "<?=$message['message']?>"(<?=anchor("home/delete/$message", 'delete')?>)</li>      
         <?php endforeach?>    
    </ul>      
  </div>
```

Comment: Where does your `$from` and `$to` variables in your `delete` function come from, isn't those values undefined?

Comment: Also, it looks like you might be putting the whole `$message` array into the delete URL. Do you have an ID you could use instead?

Comment: Okay I've added these variables to the delete function; they also exist in the deleteMessage function in the model. Okay perhaps I could change the delete url to this -<?=anchor("home/delete/", 'delete')?> but this hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Then the delete function wouldn't be getting any parameters. I think you want something like `<?=anchor("home/delete/{$message['id']}", 'delete')?>`. However, from an MVC perspective it would make more sense to have the delete method of the message controller accessible through `message/delete/id` rather than putting a delete method in the home controller (since you aren't deleting a home record).

Comment: @Hannah_B - What I think Tom meant was that you should supply the `id` for the actual message and not the message body.

Comment: Ok I tried this and the page went blank and showed up with the friends name in the url - may a good sign - but when I did it again now nothing happens. does my function when looking need much more within to actually delete the message? I dont actually have a messages controller, just a model, which is why I'm putting this function in the home controller